# how to display toast when email or mms is received to the other person

Tags: android

I am sending emails and mms in my project. I want to show a tost when email or mms is received to the recipient. I am using built-in email and messaging application. I don't know how to implement this please help.

thanx

Comment: Your question title and question body ask different things. Do you want to display the Toast when the message is sent or when it is received by the other person?

Comment: can  u add yr code that what u use for send mail..?

Answer (score 0):

Is the recipient has your software installed on their machine also?

If not - I can't think of a way to do that.

In general, Both Email & SMS are guaranteed to either deliver your message, or return with an error. So you don't really need this functionality. you can toast the sender that the message was sent.

If the recipient will not get it, your user *will* get an indication from their email / sms sending facility.